# Dataflow Job to put csv to bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I am having a simple dataflow job to write a CSV file to bigquery. I am using BigQUeryIO.write with one parDo to create tablerow. The job ran for 40min and than eventually failed with error message.

**The csv size is 30GB with around 25,00,00,000 records.**

**A work item was attempted 4 times without success. Each time the worker eventually lost contact with the service.**

Is there any recommended approach to load a huge csv file to bigquery using dataflow. Down the line i have to do some custom transformation over the data that is why using dataflow. Currently just testing the load time.

```
@ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {

        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();
        String[] parts = c.element().split("(?<!\\\\),");
        try{
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            tableRow.set(CreateTableRow.sourceField.get(i), parts[i].replaceAll("\\\\,", ","));

        }
        }catch(RuntimeException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        c.output(tableRow);
    }
```

Also getting a warning :
Autoscaling: Unable to reach resize target in zone us-central1-a. QUOTA_EXCEEDED: Quota 'CPUS' exceeded.  Limit: 8.0 in region us-central1.

But i am not deciding the region where job needs to run.

It is creating 7 compute engine which i can see but all are very basic size n1-standard-1 (1 vCPU, 3.75 GB memory). But can i control this?

**Dataflow Job ID : 2018-09-22_04_40_15-17093046238840040545**

Stats When The Job Failed :
**Workers

8 -> 0
Current state

Auto-scaling: Raised the number of workers to 593 based on the rate of progress in the currently running step(s).
Resource metrics
Current vCPUs   8
Total vCPU time     3.464 vCPU hr
Current memory  30 GB
Total memory time   12.99 GB hr
Current PD  1.95 TB
Total PD time   865.974 GB hr
Current SSD PD  0 B
Total SSD PD time   0 GB hr**

The writing code:

```
dataValue.apply(ParDo.of(new CreateTableRow()))
    .apply(BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(tableSpec)
            .withSchema(CreateTableRow.getSchema())
            .withCustomGcsTempLocation(valueProvider)
            .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
            .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
```

The reading code :

```
TextIO.read().from("gs://test-n/dummyData.csv")
```

**Is there anyway to improve performance with less workers. The reading csv part or create table row part. Can it be optimised to work better with less workers?**

**Changed the region to asia-northeast since quota was high there and upgraded the machine type to n1-standard-8. And the job got finished very quickly. Guess it was due to machine type internally heap space error might be coming.**

Anyhow its working now.

Comment: Is this a one off load or recurring? You can control the number of workers using the `maxNumWorkers` and `numWorkers` flags/options.

Comment: In addition to Graham's suggestion it is best practice to specify the region you deploying into as quota is bound to the region.

Comment: Can you please post the code for the read(). Depending on how you are performing the read the process may be getting pinned to a single worker.

Comment: It is spawning 7workers. And it has happened 3times. I am using TextIO.read
TextIO.read().from("gs://test-n/dummyData.csv")

Comment: gave the region as europe-west but getting the below warning 

Autoscaling: Unable to reach resize target for the worker pool in zone europe-west1-d. 

How can i know the limit of wrkers for a region?

Comment: Is it that BigQueryIO.write waits for the previous parDo to get completed? Or it writes the result it gets. Is there any other way to write to bigquery using dataflow?

Comment: I would just put the file in GCS and use the BigQuery WebUI to import it.

Comment: Yeah i already mentioned that part above. The requirement is to use dataflow since down the line there are custom transformation thats needs to be done.

Comment: Is it because i am on a free trial and even though it tries to spawn 250 workers it is able to spawn only 8. In case it spawns 250 workers will it work as expected?

Comment: Is there anyway to improve performance with less workers. The reading csv part or create table row part. Can it be optimised to work better with less workers?